# transaction.atomic() rolls back if another query is executed

Tags: python, django, select-for-update

I am having issues with `Django`'s `transaction.atomic`. I have this app that users can update their information, but I will be giving an example here using `age`, but in reality it will be something like an account balance.

So I want to prevent update to this field if more than one requests is received concurrently, so I want to lock the row which is why I am using `transaction.atomic` and `select_for_update`. So I have a `UserProfile` model that I want to update some information, the method which i use to update is below:

```py
Class Profile(models.Model):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.__class__.objects.filter(id=self.id)

    @transaction.atomic()
    def update_age(
        self,
        age: int,
    ) -> None:
        obj = self.get_queryset().select_for_update().get()
        obj.age = age
        obj.save()
```

Below is the view

```py
class UserProfileView(APIView):
    
    def put(self, request):
        profile = rquest.user.profile
        profile.update_age(request.data["age"])
    
        UpdateHistory.objects.create(user=request.user, updated_field="age")
```

The issue is `UpdateHistory` object is created but the `age` update is rolled back, but when I remove the creation of the `UpdateHistory`, the `age` is updated successfully. So the above code only creates `UpdateHistory`, but doesn’t update `UserProfile.age`. But if I remove the line `UpdateHistory.objects.create(user=request.user, updated_field="age")`, the `age` is updated successfully.

No exception is being raised at all, this has been confusing me for days. Hopefully I can get some help. Thanks in advance

Comment: what flavor of database are you using?

Comment: PostgreSQL. Thanks

Comment: Please share a [mre]. There's no way the current code you share with no exceptions occuring (as you mention) can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would have just used a [django `update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#topics-db-queries-update):

```py
self.get_queryset().update(age=age)
```

Comment: I’m trying to lock the row, to prevent updating concurrently, that’s why I’m using select_for _update. There is tendency of multiple update at once.